# Why does `tokio::main` report the error "cycle detected when processing"?

Tags: rust, async-await, udp, rust-tokio

I'm using Tokio and `async`/`.await` to create an UDP server where I can receive and send data in an asynchronous way.

The `SendHalf` of my UDP socket is shared across more than one task. To do this I’m using `Arc<Mutex<SendHalf>>`. That's why `Arc<Mutex<_>>` exists.

```
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;
use tokio::net::udp::SendHalf;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::net::SocketAddr;

struct Packet {
    sender: Arc<Mutex<SendHalf>>,
    buf: [u8; 512],
    addr: SocketAddr,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let server = UdpSocket::bind(("0.0.0.0", 44667)).await.unwrap();
    let (mut server_rx, mut server_tx) = server.split();
    let sender = Arc::new(Mutex::new(server_tx));
    let (mut tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(100);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut buffer = [0; 512];
            let (_, src) = server_rx.recv_from(&mut buffer).await.unwrap();
            let packet = Packet {
                sender: sender.clone(),
                buf: buffer,
                addr: src,
            };
            tx.send(packet).await;
        }
    });

    while let Some(packet) = rx.recv().await {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut socket = packet.sender.lock().unwrap();
            socket.send_to(&packet.buf, &packet.addr).await.unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

Here is also a [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ef94f7da10413677d07834b8cab9489).

I'm facing a compiler error that I don't understand:

```
error[E0391]: cycle detected when processing `main`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | #[tokio::main]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...which requires processing `main::{{closure}}#0::{{closure}}#1`...
  --> src/main.rs:34:33
   |
34 |           tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  _________________________________^
35 | |             let mut socket = packet.sender.lock().unwrap();
36 | |             socket.send_to(&packet.buf, &packet.addr).await.unwrap();
37 | |         });
   | |_________^
   = note: ...which again requires processing `main`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when processing `main::{{closure}}#0`
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | #[tokio::main]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why is my code producing a cycle? Why does the call require processing `main`?

What does the error mean in more detail? I want to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `tokio` documentation, when it comes to [using `!Send` value from a task](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.4/tokio/fn.spawn.html#using-send-values-from-a-task):

> Holding on to a `!Send` value across calls to `.await` will result in an unfriendly compile error message similar to:
>
> `[... some type ...] cannot be sent between threads safely`
>
> or:
>
> `error[E0391]: cycle detected when processing main`

You are witnessing this exact error. When you [lock a `Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock):

```rust
pub fn lock(&self) -> LockResult<MutexGuard<T>>
```

it returns a [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html), which is `!Send`:

```rust
impl<'_, T: ?Sized> !Send for MutexGuard<'_, T>
```

---

This compiles fine:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    ...

    while let Some(packet) = rx.recv().await {
        let mut socket = packet.sender.lock().unwrap();
        socket.send_to(&packet.buf, &packet.addr).await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what I'm looking for to explain the error, thanks. Your fix will compile, but it also changes the behaviour. I don't want a blocking call in the while loop. Is there a better way to share the `SendHalf` of my socket across tasks.

Comment: @createproblem just to make sure everyone is on the same page, which call are you saying is blocking?

Comment: @Shepmaster `socket.send_to(&packet.buf, &packet.addr).await.unwrap();` this is blocking, because the while loop will not process until the data is sent. Not?

Comment: @createproblem no, that line is not blocking; that's the entire point of futures and the `async` / `.await` syntax. The code will not execute past that line until the send is complete, but other async tasks may still make progress — nothing is **blocked**.

Comment: That being said, `Mutex::lock` **is blocking** and will prevent *all* tasks from continuing. Generally, you want to reduce the usage of such types (ideally to zero) in async code.

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into a very similar issue (I was using `RwLock` vs `Mutex`, but the structure is almost exactly the same). I wanted to process each UDP packet asynchronously, rather than waiting to process before reading another packet, like some other solutions here.

The change I made to solve the problem was to use `tokio::sync::*` synchronisation Structs, rather than the ones from `std`. So in your case, switch out `std::sync::Mutex` to `tokio::sync::Mutex` (and switch your `.unwrap()` to `.await`), and you should be okay. ([Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/index.html#structs))

I made the changes to your playground, and it is compiling now:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2b6114a12a5f784a38a595bc521f6f02

(Also much thanks to the Tokio Slack for providing the answer to me when I had the same question. Just passing it along).

Comment: Please, your solution being different doesn't make my answer wrong. It addressed the root cause and provided a way out. Also do the common courtesy of reading the comments before downvoting.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The original poster wanted the data to be sent without blocking the loop from continuing. My solution solves that problem -- or at the very least maintains the spirit of the code -- unfortunately yours does not.

That being said, your solution does answer the "why" part of the question appropriately, which is extremely valuable.